# Iphone iOS 6 Image corruption in skysphere

Tags: google-chrome, three.js

Using the code from

https://vr.chromeexperiments.com/

Any ideas why i'm getting this strange scanline effect with Iphone 6 chrome/safari?

Any size JPG or PNG, doesn't matter. Also tried setting the minfilter and magfilters to nearest.

It's fine on android and PC (all browsers)

Code:

```
      var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
      light.position.set(0,0,0);
      scene.add(light);

      skysphere = new THREE.Mesh(
              new THREE.SphereGeometry(160, 100, 100),
              new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color:0xffffff })
              );

      scene.add(skysphere);

      var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(
                 "an_image.jpg"
        );

      \\same problem with or without setting filters
      texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
      texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestMipMapLinearFilter;
      skysphere.material.map = texture;

      \\I've tried this and setting the scale x to -1
      skysphere.material.side = THREE.BackSide;
      skysphere.material.needsUpdate = true;
```

[image: iphone 6 screengrab]

Comment: so your image is power of two?

Comment: No it isn't, but I tried setting the filters as suggested, same problem

Comment: Unrelated: `SphereGeometry( 160, 100, 100 )` -- Yikes! Try `( 160, 24, 12 )`, or so.

Comment: the devises' opengl-es implementation probably does not support non-power-of-two texture sizes.

Comment: ok thanks, I will correct my code and test with power of 2

Comment: Making the image square (power of 2) fixed the problem, thanks a lot